# Shell script - using source command with if statement

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I have a script which using if statement as below:

```
if [ "$_nowTime" \> "$_authExpiration" ]; then
    echo "Your last token has expired"
    promptForMFA
  fi
```

when I run it via "source" or "'" command I get an error  "condition expected: >", seems like the source doesn't like the backslash, in case I remove it, it treat it as a pipe and create a file.

Comment: I use zsh.
I solved it like that -  if [ "$_nowTime > $_authExpiration" ]; then...

Comment: My mistake, as well what I mention before didn't really solve it

Comment: Ok, please show how to set the values for `$_nowTime` and `$_authExpiration` too. I assumed that you stored numerical values in them when I wrote my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: A redirection is not a pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding another square:
if [[ "$_nowTime" > "$_authExpiration" ]]

Comment: Can you accept your own answer, please, so your question doesn't stay open?